# Rjava/Rserve pass arguments from java to R

Tags: r

I am unable to pass string argument from Java to R:

```
RConnection connection = new RConnection();
connection.eval(String.format("trainingDataPath%s'","C:\\\\software\\\\"));
        connection.eval("source('C:\\\\software\\\\svm.R')"); Get an error object trainingDataPath does not exist in Rserve...Guess parse error.
kindly help
in R
dataText<-read.csv(paste(trainingDataPath,"RiskText.csv",sep=""),header= TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be the parsing of backslashes in your OS-specific Java and R. Instead of hard-coding the path completely try to use the path separator[Java Docs related to File separator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) and concatenate it with other parts of the string.